# Is it possible to have a Generic class not requiring new() with single method requiring new()?

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible in C# to have a method of a generic driven class require new, but not require new on the whole class?

```
public class Response<T> //not where T:new() 
{      
    public void AddTotal<T>() where T : new()
    {
         var totaledObject = new T();
        // do all the useful stuff I need with the new generic
    }

}
```

I use this response for many different scenarios, the T does not always have a new(), and for those scenarios I will not use the AddTotal function, but for a few I would like to have it. Is this possible?

Note:
I know I can do a different generic variable name and just pass that to the function, but this breaks the indication that it has to be of the same type as T.

Comment: "for those scenarios I will not use the AddTotal function, but for a few I would like to have it." - so why not have a `public class ResponseWithAddTotal<T> : Response<T> where T : new() { public void AddTotal<T>() { /* ... */ } }` and use it in those cases?

Comment: Which is better, a hacky looking method to require new via second generic, or an entire new derived type that only adds an additional method? Or simply requiring an already initialized variable of T as an argument? @Corak? @Yuval Itzchakov?

Comment: The solution of @Yuval has the benefit that you only have to change the one class and everything else can remain the same. With my suggestion, you may have to change some of the instantiations of the base class to the derived class. On the other hand it seems "cleaner" to only provide the functionality you actually need. If you never need `AddTotal` in most places, then why provide it? Only provide it in places you need it. A single derived class with only one method might seem like a waste, but most of the time, the problem is too much functionality in a class and not too little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible in C# to have a method of a generic driven class
>   require new, but not require new on the whole class?

Only if you specify different type parameter, which you don't want to do. A generic type parameter constraint exists for any generic type argument you specify. As you want `T` for the class and method declaration to be the same `T`, the constraint will exist for both.

If you want to specify another generic type parameter, you could do something hacky like this:

```
public class X<T>
{
    public void Y<OtherT>() where OtherT : T, new()
    {
    }
}
```

Thus constraining `OtherT` to be of type `T` declared in the class or a derivative. There's no guarantee there will be an exact match on the type.

Comment: To clarify, even if I don't use the method requiring the constraint the class I pass for the generic will still have to pass the constraint?

Comment: That's hacky, but it'll work in my scenario, apparently I now have to wait 8 minutes to give you your credit for this excellent answer

Comment: Even if you don't use the method, yes. `T` will be used for the class declaration and for the method declaration. BTW, when using `T` on the method *and* the class, you're actually shadowing the class level declaration, and `T` won't be the same for both.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this by pushing the problem out to the calling code. Add an argument to either have the calling code provide the object instance you need or have the calling code provide the method you need to create the object:

```
public void AddTotal<T>(T totaledObject) 
{
    // do all the useful stuff I need with totaledObject
}

//call it: AddTotal(new Object())
```

or

```
public void AddTotal<T>(Func<T> createObject) 
{
     var totaledObject = createObject();
    // do all the useful stuff I need with the new generic
}
```

The trick with this option is that you can't just pass a constructor to that object. You have to wrap calls in another delegate, which can be done with a quick lambda expression:

```
AddTotal(() => new Object());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to constrain T to new (). Just allow it. Use 'where T : class, new()' as your class constraint. You don't need anything on the method as new T() can now be used.

Comment: But not all generic types passed to the class have a default constructor.

Comment: right, just as Yuval said, existing classes passed in do not all have a default constructor

Comment: I see, so you would not be able to use such a class as T. Could you not add an empty default constructor for their use in this class?

Comment: @SteveHarris I'm looking into that possibility, but it's unlikely to be an option due to the number of existing classes, and the accessibility of the code, it's used in a large number of places